# Display the validation errors for each field with ValidationError being raised

Tags: django, validationerror

Only found old answers and examples I didn't understand about displaying errors in the view.

I've created a `clean_message` method in my `forms.py`, that checks if the `self.message` has something, and raises a `ValidationError` in case not.

```
"""
Comment
"""
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Comment field
    """
    comment = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs = {
                'class': 'form-control',
                'rows': 2 
            }
        )
    )

    def clean_comment(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['comment'] is None:
            raise form.ValidationError({'comment': ['You must enter your comment'])
```

And this is the view file. What do I need to display the errors, built like shown above?

```
<form action="comment" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.comment.errors }}
        {{ form.comment }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Say it" class="btn btn-success"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried to use {{ form.errors }}, iterate over it, to use {{ form.non_field_errors }} etc, but none worked. I guess somehow I am reloading the form, and thus the messages aren't displayed.

Comment: There is `{{ form.errors }}`. I guess Django docs are quite clear in explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

To display the errors at form level, you can simply use: `{{ form.errors }}`. But it seems you want field level error message. For that, you need to modify the clean method as such:

```
def clean_message(self):
    if not self.message:
        raise ValidationError({'message': ['You must enter your comment'])
```

This way, the error will be set on appropriate `field.errors`.

Comment: Am I missing something? I've done what you said, but no messages at all. Maybe put an `else`, in case the form is not valid?

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes How are you displaying errors? Did you use `form.errors`? Or `field.errors`?

Comment: I've used `form.errors`. Where would I get `field` from? Right now, I've moved the `clean_comment` to `forms.py`, according to another example.

Comment: I've updated my question with the new codes. Please, take a look.